# I have a error in my e-commerce website, "'X' is not defined no-undef"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

Error:

```
./src/reducers/productReducers.js
  Line 3:10:  'PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 5:10:  'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 7:10:  'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL' is not defined     no-undef
```

And my code down below

```
function productListReducer(state = { products: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, products: [] };
    case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, products: action.payload };
    case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export { productListReducer };
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you defined these action types?. I think you forgot to import these action types from your respective file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean't to provide action types as strings or forgot to import it from other file

You can use it like

```
function productListReducer(state = { products: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST':
      return { loading: true, products: [] };
    case 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS':
      return { loading: false, products: action.payload };
    case 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL':
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export { productListReducer };
```

or by defining and importing actionTypes like

actionTypes.js

```
export const PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST = 'PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST';
export const PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS = 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS';
export const PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL = 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL';
```

and import in reducer like

```
import {PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST} from '/path/to/actionTypes.js'
```

before using them like

```
function productListReducer(state = { products: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, products: [] };
    case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, products: action.payload };
    case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export { productListReducer };
```

Comment: Please let me know if the above solution works for you or not

Answer (score 0):

did you import your types? like this

types.js

`export TYPE_1 = "TYPE_1"`
`export TYPE_2 = "TYPE_2"`

Reducers.js:

`import {TYPE_1, TYPE_1}`

`...your codes`

Answer (score 0):

You fail to import import `{ PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL }` create a constants folder in your src folder, inside constants folder create productConstants.js

Your productConstants.js should look like this

```
export const PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST = 'PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST';
export const PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS = 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS';
export const PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL = 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL';
```

Now you should import `{ PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL } into  productReducers.js` and it should look like this

```
import { PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL } from "../constants/productConstants";

function productListReducer(state={products:[]}, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
        return {loading: true};
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {loading:false, products: action.payload };
            case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
                return { loading:false, error: action.payload}
                default:
                    return state;
    }
}

export {productListReducer};
```